"<package> <version> or newer" vs "<package> <version> and newer"
We're writing a README for an open-source project and, somewhere in the manual, we need to give installation instructions.
I wrote for one section:

In Ubuntu 23.04 or newer, <OUR SOFTWARE> can be installed
directly from the package repositories with:

However, my colleague wrote in another section:

In Fedora 40 and newer, <OUR SOFTWARE> can be installed
directly from the package repositories with:

Is either variant more correct than the other based on the use of "or" vs "and"?

Since version numbers are a set that can be represented in order on a line, both mean "from version x onward, including version x ", right? If so, both look correct to me; do you have a particular reason to think that one of them should not be?

Both are OK. There are situations where it makes sense to use "or", since a system can only have one version. But here it's hard to see a reason to prefer one or the other. The best bet would be to try and be consistent with other packages.

Many just write "Ubuntu 40+"

@Barmar "Ubuntu 40+" isn't foolproof: some may think "I have Ubuntu 40, not 40+. am I still good?

@DjinTonic I've never heard of anyone interpreting it that way. AFAIK X+ is always interpreted as >= X, not > X

@Barmar I wasn't referring to Fedora specifically, but rather the addition of a plus sign to a product name in general.

@Barmar I wasn't referring to Fedora specifically, but rather the addition of a plus sign to a product name in general. A newcomer might think that the product is named "Fedora 40" rather than Fedora (version 40) and that "Fedora 40+" is a different product/model.

Oh, I see what you mean -- they might think that + is part of the name/version, like Apple TV+. Yes, the recent trend to use + in naming things could cause confusion.

Maybe a better question is "is either one unclear." The answer to that is "no"; I don't see a way that either "23 and newer" or "23 or newer" could be taken as excluding either 23 or 24.

If the company isn't sure that the information will remain valid for future versions 41 and higher, perhaps "In Fedora versions that start with 40" or similar

From Ubuntu 23.04 onwards...
